# Install Windows (overwriting Linux)?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, uefi, windows-installation, bootable-media

My netbook came with Windows 8 and then I put Linux Mint on it (overwriting Windows). I am now trying to do the reverse: reinstall Windows and overwrite Linux. I have tried installing from a USB.

I have put the Win8 iso on a USB using:

- the default system tool
- Unetbootin

Neither install method worked. Note it is a UEFI BIOS. 
I have also tried Windows 7 and Windows 10.

The USB drive either doesn't show up and when it does it says that it cannot find a bootable disk to start from.

Comment: As it is currently written, we can't really help you. Please edit your question and add additional information. What is not working? What have you tried? What error do you get (if applicable)? Basically, where are things not working? Otherwise I would just say, put in the dvd and boot from there and install windows. Now this obviously is not going to work, but your question does not really tell us where you need help.

Comment: Alright sorry for not being clear enough :

What is not working: I cannot install windows over the Linux Mint OS that I have currently installed on my PC.

What have you tried: I have tried booting from a USB. I have tried this in a couple different ways, that being through Unetbootin and the default tool for making a bootable USB stick. 

What error do you get: The USB either doesnt show up and when it does it says that it cannot find a bootable disk to start from.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a UEFI bios, you have to create a UEFI-bootable USB key

here is a procedure to do so :

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html

Comment: The only problem with this is that I dont have windows so I cant use any of that stuff.

Comment: and you don't knwo anybody with a windows computer? Maybe you could setup a Windows VM on your current linux and connect the USB to the VM.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.